# Calling a parent jQuery function from an iframe when using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cordova

I have a web application that uses PhoneGap.
In the application I open an Iframe for executing a credit card transaction and when the transaction is completed I want to close the Iframe.

When the application is running on a regular browser everything is working great. This is the command I use:

```
parent.$("#ExecuteApplicationPage").dialog("close")
```

It is working on the browser , but when I am working on the same app which was build with PhoneGap, I get the error :"$ is undefined". Obviously ,for some reason, the parent window doesn't have jQuery loaded.
 Do you have an idea why this could happen only on PhoneGap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem for me was to pass a (phonegap) command to the parent window, and respond to that command.